# Write queries results into a file in prolog

Tags: database, logging, prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

Here is my prolog database code.

```
:-
    dynamic myTable/2.

init :-
    removeAll,
    asserta(myTable('avalue', 'another value')),
    asserta(myTable('avalue1', 'another value 1')),
    asserta(myTable('avalue2', 'another value 2')),
    asserta(myTable('avalue3', 'another value 3')),
    asserta(myTable('avalue4', 'another value 4')).

read(Col1, Col2) :-
    myTable(Col1, Col2).

saveQueries(FileName) :-
    tell(FileName).

stopSavingQueries :-
    told.
```

I want to start saving prolog output into a file. Make some queries to the dynamic database, which should be saved into the file, and then stop saving the queries. It would look something like this

```
?- init.
true.

?- saveQueries('queries.txt').
true.

?- read(Col1, Col2).
...
?- stopSavingQueries.
true.
```

When I run this code file `queries.txt` is created. When I run `read(Col1, Col2).` I see the output in the console and the file `queries.txt` remains empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling for a while I found this solution.

```
saveQueries(FileName) :-
    protocol(FileName).

stopQueriesSaving :-
    noprotocol.
```

Then I can do this

```
?- saveQueries('queries.txt').
true.

/* execute some queries here */

?- stopQueriesSaving.
true.
```

After I execute those commands I have a file `queries.txt` which contains all the queries and their results.